# How to align WPF Expander control toggle button

Tags: wpf, button, controls, toggle, expander

Hi I was wondering is it possible to align the toggle button on a WPF expander control to the far right side?

Comment: Why do u have to do such lengthy process when there is a simple process here in the link provided below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288342/how-to-put-wpf-expander-toggle-button-on-right

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With WPF all things are possible. ;) Unfortunately not all things are simple. Your best bet here is to re-template the expander. Start out by copying the default `Expander` template, found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx).

Next, find the `Grid` that contains 2 columns, one containing a `ToggleButton` and the other containing a `ContentPresenter`. Swap the columns so the toggle is in column 1. Then change the column definition sizes so the first column is star-sized, and the second is size 20. When finished, you should have a chunk in the template that looks like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
      OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
      Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}" 
      Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" />
    <ContentPresenter Margin="4" 
      ContentSource="Header" 
      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
</Grid>
```

Continue modifying the template until you get the look and feel that you need.

**EDIT**: The template provided on MSDN is a bare-bones version of the "real" expander template. If you want the stylized expander template, use Expression Blend and copy the existing control template off an `Expander`.