# How to put Expander ToggleButton on right

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

By default the expander has a left aligned toggle button but in my WPF app i want toggle button on the right side of the header without the help of Expression Blend. just plain XAML and/or C#. My expander contains a vertically oriented stackpanel which has labels as its child.

I went for its part but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx) it says "The Expander control does not have any named parts".

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587683/how-to-align-wpf-expander-control-toggle-button). But it overrides the default Expander Style.

I think the attached image should convey what i want. How to do. Any link would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
<Expander Header="Expander1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
    </TextBlock>
</Expander>
```

Add your content in the `TextBlock`, if you don't want to the whole content to be right to left.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal As I said, you should put your content inside a LeftToRight container (`TextBlock` in my example). You can set `FlowDirection` of your `StackPanel` to `LeftToRight`.

Comment: I did what u suggested. My expander contains a vertically oriented  stackpanel (Orientation = Vertical) which has labels as its child (Added Dynamically). I set the expander FlowDirection="RightToLeft" and stackpanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" and it worked. Thanks

Comment: This will align the header to the right of the window.

Answer (score 18):

There is a trick that can help

```
<Expander Header="My Expander" 
          FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, Path=Header}"
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                       Margin="-30,0,0,0"
                       FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Can you please explaing how your answer is different from MD.Unicorn's answer?

Comment: Yes. With his answer the Header text will be right aligned as well along with the ToggleButton. In my solution Header text is still left aligned and just ToggleButton is shifted from Left to Right.

Comment: Though the questioner didn't expect this answer or probably didn't really need this, it helped me out with my own problem. Cheers!